# ID of a Python thread as reported by top

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, ctypes

I am starting a bunch of different threads in my Python script. I want to keep track of the memory and CPU usage of each of these threads. I use `top` and `ps -eLf` for that.

But it turns out that the identifier returned by `thread.start_new_thread()` is different from the thread PID displayed by `top` and other similar programs. Is there a way to obtain this PID from with in the Python script? This way, I can determine which PID belongs to which thread.

Comment: Instead of parsing top, you can peruse /proc/main_PID/task and get a list of your child threads and their memory usage.

Comment: @ers81239 Thanks! But what exactly should I look for in here. All the directories in there look very similar. I want to correlate which tid belongs to which thread as one of those threads is using a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Get-thread-pid-td1536295.html), I got the Python threads to report their respective thread IDs. First do a `grep -r 'SYS_gettid' /usr/include/'`. I got a line: `#define SYS_gettid __NR_gettid` Upon further grepping by `grep -r '__NR_gettid' /usr/include/`, I got a bunch of matching lines:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_32.h:#define __NR_gettid 224
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h:#define __NR_gettid 186
/usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h:#define __NR_gettid 178
```

Now choose the one that matches your architecture. Mine was 186. Now include this code in all your Python thread scripts to get the thread ID as seen by the OS:

```
import ctypes
tid = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6').syscall(186)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a patch to replace the python thread identifier with the `TID` as displayed in `htop`:

```
def patch_thread_identifier():
    """Replace python thread identifier by TID."""
    # Imports
    import threading, ctypes
    # Define get tid function
    def gettid():
        """Get TID as displayed by htop."""
        libc = 'libc.so.6'
        for cmd in (186, 224, 178):
            tid = ctypes.CDLL(libc).syscall(cmd)
            if tid != -1:
                return tid
    # Get current thread
    current = threading.current_thread()
    # Patch get_ident (or _get_ident in python 2)
    threading.get_ident = threading._get_ident = gettid
    # Update active dictionary
    threading._active[gettid()] = threading._active.pop(current.ident)
    # Set new identifier for the current thread
    current._set_ident()
    # Done
    print("threading._get_ident patched!")
```

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using?

With the exception of very old versions of Linux, each thread should have the same PID (Process ID). The identifier on thread.start_new_thread() is internal to python and is used to identify a particular thread of execution.

For more information on linux threading, see the pthreads man page on Linux.

Comment: Well, its not really the PID that I am referring to here, its the tid which is reported as a 'PID' by say, `top` on pressing the `H` key to view all the threads.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 11.10 version.